# Distribute COUNT for Types seperated by /

Tags: powerbi, dax, data-analysis, powerbi-desktop, measure

I have the following table :

```
OP Type                         OP ID
Client vs Client                125
Client vs N                     5636
B vs N Client                   54
Client vs Client/B vs N Client  51
Client vs Client                4
Client vs Client/B vs N Client  5
Client vs N                     31
B vs N Client/ Client vs N      45
```

I want to calculate the number of OP ID by  OP Type using this condition :
When for example we have :
a type seperated by / like Client vs Client/B vs N Client

the count will be like below 1 goes to Client vs Client
and 1 goes to B vs N Client      1
and 1 remains  for Client vs Client/B vs N Client
The output will be :

```
OP                                Count
Client vs Client                  4
Client vs N                       3
B vs N Client                     4
Client vs Client/B vs N Client    2
B vs N Client/ Client vs N        1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a **Measure** similar to:

```
Special Count = 
  COUNTROWS(
    FILTER(
      ALLSELECTED('YourTable'),
      CONTAINSSTRING('YourTable'[OP Type], SELECTEDVALUE('YourTable'[OP Type]))
    )
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Table:

[image]

Measure:

```
Measure = CALCULATE(COUNTROWS('Table'),  FILTER(ALLSELECTED('Table'), CONTAINSSTRING('Table'[OP Type], SELECTEDVALUE('Table'[OP Type]))))
```